# Why did SSH and ssh-copy-id stop working suddenly?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-copy-id

Very simple set up, I have two vms on GCP, one is a jenkins server, the other a nodejs server.

Yesterday, I successfully generated a rsa key (as jenkins user), and then copied it over to the nodejs server via ssh-copy-id.  Following that, I could ssh into nodejs server no problem.

Today, I log in and both ssh and ssh-copy-id fail.

ssh-copy-id output:

```
jenkins@idg-ops:~$ ssh-copy-id -i matthewcarltyson@34.foo.bar.13
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
matthewcarltyson@34.foo.bar.13: Permission denied (publickey)
```

ssh output:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:vPyeyakbpyqjcBF9KixHb7u5sSCtX4lf9bvrtsiwY2g
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

There doesn't appear to be any keys on the nodejs server for matthewcarltyson now.

odd.

On server:

```
May 24 21:26:57 idg-nodejs sshd[10609]: Did not receive identification string from 122.114.37.11 port 34782
May 24 21:27:06 idg-nodejs sshd[10611]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59434 [preauth]
May 24 21:27:06 idg-nodejs sshd[10613]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59436 [preauth]
May 24 21:27:06 idg-nodejs sshd[10615]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59438 [preauth]
May 24 21:29:56 idg-nodejs sshd[10617]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59444 [preauth]
May 24 21:29:56 idg-nodejs sshd[10619]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59446 [preauth]
May 24 21:29:56 idg-nodejs sshd[10621]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59448 [preauth]
May 24 21:30:56 idg-nodejs sshd[10623]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59450 [preauth]
May 24 21:30:56 idg-nodejs sshd[10625]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59452 [preauth]
May 24 21:30:57 idg-nodejs sshd[10627]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59454 [preauth]
May 24 21:33:14 idg-nodejs sshd[10629]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59460 [preauth]
May 24 21:33:14 idg-nodejs sshd[10631]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59462 [preauth]
May 24 21:33:14 idg-nodejs sshd[10633]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59464 [preauth]
May 24 21:45:55 idg-nodejs sshd[10686]: Did not receive identification string from 205.185.114.91 port 33754
May 24 21:47:48 idg-nodejs sshd[10687]: Connection closed by authenticating user matthewcarltyson 35.223.18.153 port 59480 [preauth]
May 24 22:14:04 idg-nodejs sshd[10740]: Did not receive identification string from 192.241.208.162 port 51702
May 24 22:17:01 idg-nodejs CRON[10741]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 24 22:17:01 idg-nodejs CRON[10741]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 24 23:01:16 idg-nodejs sshd[10848]: Did not receive identification string from 81.161.63.103 port 63924
May 24 23:01:26 idg-nodejs sshd[10849]: Connection closed by 81.161.63.103 port 12594 [preauth]
May 24 23:01:27 idg-nodejs sshd[10852]: Connection reset by authenticating user root 81.161.63.103 port 12692 [preauth]
May 24 23:01:27 idg-nodejs sshd[10856]: Connection reset by 81.161.63.103 port 12690 [preauth]
May 24 23:01:27 idg-nodejs sshd[10850]: Connection reset by authenticating user root 81.161.63.103 port 12687 [preauth]
May 24 23:01:27 idg-nodejs sshd[10851]: Connection reset by authenticating user root 81.161.63.103 port 12686 [preauth]
May 24 23:17:01 idg-nodejs CRON[10907]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 24 23:17:01 idg-nodejs CRON[10907]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: You really need to see what the server is saying; that's where the reason will be logged

Comment: @roaima Can you point me to where the logs are?

Comment: `/var/log`. On Debian systems you can look in `auth.log`.

Comment: According to the ssh output, ssh offered `id_rsa` to the server and the server didn't accept it. What key file is ssh supposed to use for these connections?

Comment: @Kenster Is that for `ssh`?  Would that affect `ssh-copy-id`?  I can understand ssh not working because the rsa key is (mysteriously) vanished... but why is ssh-copy-id not working now???

Comment: ssh-copy-id is just a shell script which uses the ssh program to try to write a public key to a file on the remote server. If ssh can't authenticate, then ssh-copy-id won't be able to do anything.

Comment: @Kenster thanks ... that makes sense.  I think I do remember using a password to auth ssh-copy-id in the first place.  Maybe I'm doing something different now when running ssh-copy-id.  I think there is a "AllowPasswordAuthentication" setting or something?  Thanks again.